# How to constantly re-loop through code until a condition is met?

Tags: java

I know you can do

```
  while(function){


 }
```

etc but  pretty much what i want to happen is:

I have 6 people:
ceri
harry
matthew
james
lewis
kwok

and i want to make a type of fixtures program so its like

```
 ceri v harry
ceri v matthew
ceri v james
ceri v kwok
```

and do that for everyone(but if ceri v harry occurs then harry v ceri can NOT appear) if you get my drift..

I would like some guidance whether an array would be best suited or...?

I am not asking for any code or for someone to do this for me as its my own little project, just guidance.

Comment: What you want is a way to print all combinations in a set.  Do some research using that word, `combination.`

Comment: You can use `Set` interface in Java's collections.

Comment: Your question is quite vague, IMO. What is it are you trying to achieve on a functional basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Luke's answer is better if you're truly looking for just a hint; read the rest of this one if you still need help :)

---

It's hard to explain without any code, but per your request, I'll try. Let's say you have all your names in an array, `names`.

Loop through each name in a `for` loop. Inside that loop, loop through the remaining names as well—for example, if your outer loop is starting at index 0, start your inner loop at index 1. For each iteration of the inner loop, you'll have a unique combination of names.

---

Now if that's still confusing, here's some code to get you started:

```
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
    for(int j=i+1;j<names.length;j++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + " v " + names[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I had already read your message.. When I look at it.. its 3 lines of code, i seriously need to spend more time thinking about the logic of it.. now I understand it, its  so simple but somehow i didnt get it. I appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you're looking for a hint but want to figure it out yourself. You're right that an array of people will be easiest.

Here's a more detailed hint (don't read if you don't want more!) You want to loop through the array, and for each person, pair him with all the people AHEAD of him in the array. In the end, you'll need a "for" loop inside a "for" loop.

Answer (score 0):

As there's no code, you could have an array:

```
String names[] = new String [] {"ceri", "harry", "matthew", ...};
```

Then compare in a for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + " v " + names[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will print both "ceri v matthew" and "matthew v cerci", I think!

Comment: hmmm yeah... you're right... let me make a class and test it

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] names = new String[] {"ceri", "harry", "matthew", ...};

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++)
        System.out.println(names[i] + " v " + names[j]);
}
```

By looping through each element and only printing that it is "v" the names after itself, the duplicate combinations are eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you'll want to use two nested for loops with two nested if statements. This will allow you to grab a name, iterate over all the other names, while checking if the result is in your resulting set in either order.

It might be worth noting that you should only have to go over half of the names in the list in order to get all the pairs without any doubles. You might also want to look into a dynamic object, like and arraylist, for storing your resultant set incase your input name list ever increases in size.